# Using ember-cli, should I "serve" or "build"?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli, broccolijs

I'm on Windows 7, ember-cli version 40. Every time I make code changes I have to quit the server and restart it as I get Broccoli "ENOENT" errors for the tmp directory every time I save some changes.

The modus operandi for the past few days has just been to Ctrl+c, then do `ember server` again. Build times are over 100 seconds. So I'm wondering if I should be doing `ember build` at some point, then `ember server` or if anyone knows why Broccoli won't rebuild automatically like it's supposed to. This is a small project right now, only a couple dependencies, but I just deleted over 6GB from the tmp folder because new stuff kept getting copied there.

**EDIT**

I upgraded to ember-cli version 42, and times on Windows 7 are down to 22sec or so, which is a big improvement

**My Brocfile.js:**

```
/* global require, module */

var pickFiles = require('broccoli-static-compiler');
var mergeTrees = require('broccoli-merge-trees');
var EmberApp = require('ember-cli/lib/broccoli/ember-app');
var fontTree;
var app = new EmberApp();

fontTree = pickFiles('vendor/fontawesome/fonts', {
  srcDir: '/',
  files: ['*'],
  destDir: '/assets/fonts'
});
// Use `app.import` to add additional libraries to the generated
// output files.
app.import('bower_components/bootstrap-sass-official/vendor/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.js');
app.import('bower_components/moment/moment.js');

//module.exports = mergeTrees([app.toTree(), fontTree]);
module.exports = app.toTree();
```

Comment: try using sudo for `ember server`

Comment: Wait 3-6 months until ember-cli and broccoli are actually ready to use. Meanwhile, buy an SSD, and move as much as possible outside the reach of broccoli by statically building things yourself when they change, starting with SCSS.

Answer (score 2):

100 seconds for a small project? You should definitely investigate the error. Typically, you just run `ember server`, and the project rebuilds when files change. Rebuilds for big projects can get upwards of 7-10 seconds, but usually that's because of a large dependency.

I would encourage you to explore the ENOENT error. Also, drop in #ember-cli on IRC (freenode) and ask there.

Comment: Thanks Sam. I've been surprised too. It is on a work laptop running windows. The same project takes ~10sec on my mac, which still seems a bit long. I'm not sure what takes so long here, because I have only added Bootstrap, Moment, and broccoli-sass. Here's an example of one of the ENOENT errors, which occur on nearly every save. Every once in a while it's fine, but rarely:

`ENOTEMPTY, directory not empty 'c:\dev\star\tmp\custom_static_compiler-tmp_dest_dir-jHVVQ2NG.tmp\vendor\bootstrap-sass-o
fficial\vendor\assets'`

Comment: Can you post your brocfile to the question?

Comment: Have you made sure to disable windows indexing/search in that directory? IIRC, that is a large known impact on perf under Windows. See https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/1294 and https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/1253

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue others have reported. There are perf problems on Windows due to Windows indexing/search. If you disable this, you should restore much of your perf. Somebody else mentioned as well that it resolved this ember serve issue for them: https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/1253

Some other links for you:
- [Slow build time in Windows Environment](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/1294)
- [Improve Windows experience](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/issues/1558)

Comment: Thanks Jason. I have disabled indexing on my /tmp folder, and tried a variety of other things as well. Should be getting a Mac soon, that should help :)

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded my app to ember-cli v 0.0.42, and right away saw my `ember server` times drop to around 20 seconds, which is still pretty slow, but much better than 180 and seems to indicate the team made some fixes that improved the Windows speed. I know the majority of the web dev community is on Apple machines, so I expect Windows support to lag, it's just the nature of the thing, which is ok.

Comment: Why is it OK to ship an unusable product?

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions of ember-cli (0.1.0) and up, I think), if you run your "ember serve" command window as administrator, a bunch of other speedups come in because now it can use symbolic links rather than copying, and at that point build times on Windows come down to the same speed as on unix/osx. (see http://www.ember-cli.com/#symlinks-on-windows)